Keras and Tensorflow not getting imported despite all installations working
I am using Python 3.9 (because some other libraries I require don't have support for Python 3.12 yet).
I have first installed Keras as per https://keras.io/getting_started/
I am verifying it as:
$ pip show keras

Name: keras
Version: 3.6.0
Summary: Multi-backend Keras.
Home-page: https://github.com/keras-team/keras
Author: Keras team
Author-email: keras-users@googlegroups.com
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /home/mohanamisra/Desktop/ibm-ai-engineering-solutions/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: absl-py, h5py, ml-dtypes, namex, numpy, optree, packaging, rich
Required-by: tensorflow


I have installed Tensorflow as per https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
I am verifying it as:
$ pip show tensorflow

Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.18.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/mohanamisra/Desktop/ibm-ai-engineering-solutions/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: absl-py, astunparse, flatbuffers, gast, google-pasta, grpcio, h5py, keras, libclang, ml-dtypes, numpy, opt-einsum, packaging, protobuf, requests, setuptools, six, tensorboard, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, termcolor, typing-extensions, wrapt
Required-by: 


I then REINSTALLED keras as per the previous docs (because I realised it requires a tensorflow installation only after my first installation).
But when I type import tensorflow as tf or import keras, I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'.
I have checked and double-checked my python version as 3.9.20.
How to resolve this?

It seems that you have installed both packages in your virtual environment (.venv). In some IDEs, you have to define the system to use that environment. Is it possible that it is not configured to use this environment?

@Ze'evBen-Tsvi I checked what you said and while it seems to be working, instead of import keras, I have to keep doing import keras.api...and then whatever I wanna import. What's the difference, if any?

I'm not sure. You have placed no code that I can reproduce the process that generates the error nor the full error messages that might hint about what is missing. So I can only guess here. Did you try to replace the Keras package imported by importing the tensorflow.keras instead? (You might want to import tensorflow first and tensorflow.keras second)

Please try again by installing the Python version 3.10 which supports all the latest Tensorflow 2.18 and Keras 3.7.
However I tried with Python version 3.9 and able to install Tensorflow version 2.18 and Keras 3.6 successfully in Google Colab.
Please have a look at the below screen shot.

Lets us know if the issue still persists. Thank you
